# EXTJS 4.1 how to remove filter without reloading of TreeStore

Tags: extjs, filter, tree, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have a TreeStore which fills with data from Json.
I'm applying filter on it.

`if ( !filter.filterFn(node) ) {
        node.remove();
     }`

For the first search attempt everything works great but at the second attempt not all data is used in the search. In order to use all data I need to do .load() for the storage.
But in this case the request to the server will be send and filter will be applied applied.
Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not certain I totally follow your question, but I think you want to remove the earlier filter before you apply a new filter.

You can add a line right before the call to add the filter.

Something like this:

```
yourTreeStore.filters.clear();
```

(where `yourTreeStore` is a reference to your `Ext.data.TreeStore` you are adding the filters to)

Comment: Well I don't want to reload to reload tree using request to server. Is there any way to hide/show node without removing it?